# Which is a better design: store single character or meaningful string in DB row?

Tags: sql

Given I have a DB table as follows:

```
<TableName>
  id: string
  sym: string
  type: string
```

I can store the data into the DB table with two methods:

```
Method one:
0001, IBM, Stock
0002, IBM18Jan, Option

Method one:
0001, IBM, '1'
0002, IBM18Jan, '2'
```

For method one, I don't need to make any conversion when I display the data.
However, I need to make a conversion from '1' to Stock and '2' to Option in method two. Basically, I have to maintenance a mapping somewhere in the query code.

Question> Which method is better? Obviously, by using method two, I can save lots of DB space but the conversion is required in later query statements.

Comment: Just normalize your data. First of all, id should be numeric, then type could be a foreign key for another table which will hold the descriptions table_type(id, name) and tableName(id, sym, type_id).

Answer (score 1):

This might be perceived as a matter of opinion.  However, I strongly think that inscrutable codes that require magic external knowledge are a big design choice for databases -- and for any software.

Relational databases give you a simple solution -- reference tables.  You can store the "1"s and "2" if you like.  Then you can have another table that expands the definitions into their full names.

Some databases support other types -- such as `enum`s -- that do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on frequency of usage/change and size of reference data. If reference data  is very large in terms of number of rows then though you will save time in conversion but you will lose time when you want to update any of the value or if you want to use this reference data in you other queries. Also reference table makes maintenance and updation of data easier.